# Olympiad Math Question - If the sum of the positive inverses of 4 positive integers equals $1.1$, what’s the lowest possible sum of the integers?

Tags: contest-math, fractions

I was going through some Olympiad pass papers and came across this question:

> Given four different positive integers $A, B, C, D$ so that $\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}+ \frac{1}{C}+\frac{1}{D}=1.1$. Find the smallest possible value of $A+B+C+D$.

Does the value $1.1$ have to do with anything? Also, what trick can I use to solve this question? Is there an inverse equation formula of some type I can use?

I tried doing this:

$$\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}+ \frac{1}{C}+\frac{1}{D}=1.1$$
$$ABC+BCD+ACD+ABD=1.1ABCD$$

But now I don’t know where to continue. Also, this is an Olympiad math question, which means I probably need an answer that can solve the question in 2 minutes or less.

Comment: $1.1 = 11/10$ might help

Comment: @Om3ga If I remember correct, there was a formula that could be used to add unit fractions to equal any fraction. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: What kind of math olympiad requires an answer in 2 minutes?! Most olympiads I know give 3-4 hours for 3-4 problems...

Comment: @Qi Zhu Ah, see, I’m an eighth grader. There are two parts to this Olympiad. The first part is multiple choice and has 15 questions. The second part is open-ended and has 10 questions. All of the questions need to be done in an hour.

Comment: @Tyrcnex is this question from SOF Math Olympiad?

Comment: @Om3ga No, it’s from WMI.

Comment: @Tyrcnex Strange. Considering the difficulty of this problem and the conditions/restrictions given, the time provided is less

Comment: @QiZhu AMC 8 has 40 minutes for 25 questions. AMC 10 and AMC 12 have 75 minutes for 25 questions. For a lower-level contest, I think this kind of time constraint is not uncommon.

Comment: @Om3ga This was one of the harder questions :’)

Comment: @VTand Yes, but those are usually not called Olympiads. Plus, at the AMC one (at least the more experienced students) would usually solve the first problems very quickly, so there is more time for the latter problems.

Comment: @Tyrcnex I see. But from what you've said, there is more time than just $2$ minutes, especially since this is supposed to be one of the harder problems. Sometimes uglier problems do appear in contests, one just has to be practiced to do a somewhat quick brute force approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose $A < B < C < D$.

Notice that if $A \ge 3$, then $B \ge 4$, $C \ge 5$, $D \ge 6$, and then $\tfrac{1}{A}+\tfrac{1}{B}+\tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} \le \tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{4}+\tfrac{1}{5}+\tfrac{1}{6} = \tfrac{19}{20} < 1.1$. So we need $A = 1$ or $A = 2$.

**Case 1**: $A = 2$. Then we need $\tfrac{1}{B}+\tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} = \tfrac{3}{5}$ with $2 < B < C < D$.

Since $\tfrac{3}{B} > \tfrac{1}{B}+\tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} = \tfrac{3}{5}$, we must have $B < 5$, i.e. $B = 3$ or $B = 4$.

If $B = 4$, we need $\tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} = \tfrac{7}{20}$ with $4 < C < D$. Since $\tfrac{2}{C} > \tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} = \tfrac{7}{20}$, we must have $C < \tfrac{40}{7}$, i.e. $C \le 5$. Since $4 < C \le 5$, we must have $C = 5$, but then $D = \tfrac{20}{3}$, which is not an integer. So there are no solutions with $A = 2$ and $B = 4$.

If $B = 3$, we need $\tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} = \tfrac{4}{15}$ with $3 < C < D$. Since $\tfrac{2}{C} > \tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} = \tfrac{4}{15}$, we must have $C < \tfrac{15}{2}$, i.e. $C \le 7$. Testing $C = 4, 5, 6, 7$ yields $D = 60, 15, 10, \tfrac{105}{13}$ respectively. In this case, the smallest sum where $C$ and $D$ are integers is $21$ which occurs for $(A,B,C,D) = (2,3,6,10)$.

**Case 2**: $A = 1$. Then, we need $\tfrac{1}{B}+\tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} = \tfrac{1}{10}$. But since $\tfrac{3}{D} < \tfrac{1}{B}+\tfrac{1}{C}+\tfrac{1}{D} = \tfrac{1}{10}$, any solution in this case will have $D > 30$, and thus, $A+B+C+D > 30 > 21$. So we will not find a smaller sum in this case.

Therefore, the minimum sum is $21$.

---

Note that if you just need to get an answer quickly without a rigorous proof, then you can probably just guess and check until you find something reasonably small. In problems with Egyptian fractions (fractions with numerator $1$), the sum $\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{6} = 1$ comes up a lot, namely it is the smallest set of distinct Egyptian fractions that add up to $1$. So it's not too hard to build off of that to get $\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{6}+\tfrac{1}{10} = \tfrac{11}{10}$. I'm not sure if there is an easy way to convince yourself that's the smallest sum though.

Comment: Would this be something an 8th grade Math Olympiad should know? I forgot to mention that I’m an 8th grader :)

Comment: I have no idea what 8th grade math olympiad problems are supposed to require contestants know these days, but the HM-AM inequality is probably the easiest way to get the answer to this question (besides simply assuming without justification that the minimum sum occurs when $A = B = C = D$). I remember learning [RMS-AM-GM-HM](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) around 8th grade (plus or minus a year), so it's not totally unreasonable for a math contest to expect that from 8th grader students.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Note that there is a restriction: the four numbers are different positive integers.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Ha, my classmates are still struggling with graphing linear lines. Anyways, I’ve never heard of HM-AM, but would I be able to solve this question in under 2 minutes, assuming I had prior knowledge of this concept?

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see that restriction. I'll delete this answer since it doesn't apply to the problem.

Comment: This new answer seems a little like brute force… not as elegant as I would have hoped.

Comment: Indeed, it's basically brute force. The distinct positive integer restriction made quite the difference in how elegant the solution was. Of course, this is somewhat expected as discrete optimization is in general harder than continuous optimization.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply brute-force all possibilities. Assume $A < B < C < D$.

- If $A \geq 3$, then $\frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{B} + \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{D} \leq \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} < 0.34 + 0.25 + 0.2 + 0.17 = 0.96 < 1.1$.
- Suppose $A = 2$.

  - If $B \geq 5$, then $\frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{B} + \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{D} \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} < 0.5 + 0.2 + 0.17 + 0.15 = 1.02 < 1.1$.
  - Suppose $B = 4$.

    - If $C \geq 6$, then $\frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{B} + \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{D} \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} < 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.17 + 0.15 = 1.07 < 1.1$
    - If $C = 5$, then $\frac{1}{D} = 1.1 - \frac{1}{A} - \frac{1}{B} - \frac{1}{C} = \frac{3}{20}$. In this case, $D$ is not an integer.
  - Suppose $B = 3$.

    - If $C \geq 8$, then $\frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{B} + \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{D} \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} < 0.5 + 0.34 + 0.13 + 0.12 = 1.09 < 1.1$
    - If $C = 7$, then $\frac{1}{D} = 1.1 - \frac{1}{A} - \frac{1}{B} - \frac{1}{C} = \frac{13}{105}$. In this case, $D$ is not an integer.
    - If $C = 6$, then $\frac{1}{D} = 1.1 - \frac{1}{A} - \frac{1}{B} - \frac{1}{C} = \frac{1}{10}$. So $(A, B, C, D) = (2, 3, 6, 10)$ is a solution to the equation.
    - If $C = 5$, then $\frac{1}{D} = 1.1 - \frac{1}{A} - \frac{1}{B} - \frac{1}{C} = \frac{1}{15}$. So $(A, B, C, D) = (2, 3, 5, 15)$ is a solution to the equation.
    - If $C = 4$, then $\frac{1}{D} = 1.1 - \frac{1}{A} - \frac{1}{B} - \frac{1}{C} = \frac{1}{60}$. So $(A, B, C, D) = (2, 3, 4, 60)$ is a solution to the equation.
- Suppose $A = 1$. Then $$\frac{1}{B} + \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{D} = \frac{1}{10}.$$
  If $D < 30$, then $$\frac{1}{B} + \frac{1}{C} + \frac{1}{D} > \frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{30} = \frac{1}{10}.$$ So $D$ must be at least $30$, and therefore $A+B+C+D \geq 30$.

In conclusion, the minimum sum is $21$, achieved with $(A, B, C, D) = (2, 3, 6, 10)$.

---

That said, this is a rather unpleasant way of dealing with this problem. In a contest, this would probably take me more than two minutes, but hopefully the easier questions in the contest takes less time so that I can spend more time here.

Comment: Yeah, this is a rather unpleasant way. I hope someone can find a more elegant solution!

Comment: Considering this appeared in a Math Olympiad, brute-forcing is not a good solution since its time consuming and rather unpleasant. But for the sake of solving the problem, its fine

Comment: @Om3ga It sure is inelegant, but it is straightforward. For a contest, I'd rather do this rather than thinking for an elegant solution that might not even exist. Even if such an elegant solution exists, I think it'll take more time to find that solution than doing this brute-force solution.

Comment: @VTand I’m just practicing for an upcoming contest, just seeing if you guys could expand my way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

As your equivalent equation shows, at least one of the numbers is even, and at least one must be divisible by $5$. Since we are trying to make the numbers as small as possible, let's see if $2$ and $5$ will do the trick. Now $0.5+0.2=0.7$, leaving $0.4$ to make up with two Egyptian fractions (EFs). Starting with the smallest denominator, namely $3$, we are already lucky: $\frac13+\frac1{15}=0.4$. Can we do better than this? Our target to beat is $2+3+5+15=25$. So we are looking for four positive integers, including at least one even number and one multiple of $5$, which add to $24$ or less, whose reciprocals sum to $1.1$.

Clearly $1$ can be excluded, because that would leave us having to find three EFs summing to $0.1$, and the denominator sum would exceed $30$. Next comes $2$ (as before). That leaves a three-term EF sum of 0.6. It’s easy to spot $\frac13+\frac16+\frac1{10}=0.6$. Our integer sum target is now $20$ or less. Note that if any number has a prime-power factor not dividing $10$, then another has that factor too. Hence we can forget $7,8,9$, any of $11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18$, and $19$, and larger numbers, since the inclusion of any one would drive our sum over $20$. What is left to play with is $2,3,4,5,6$ and $10$. It is clear that
$$\frac12+\frac13+\frac16+\frac1{10}=1.1$$
cannot be bettered.